# Finding a Monoid

Tags: monoid, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

I want to find the monoid $ colim_n \pi_0 (\mathcal{I} M_n(\mathbb{C})) $ which I know is isomorphic to $ \pi_0 (colim_n  \mathcal{I} M_n(\mathbb{C})) $ where $ \mathcal{I}$ is the set of idempotents  .

Any help on how to get started?

Please and thank you!

Comment: idempotent = projection on a subspace...

Comment: @GrigoryM Yeah ... I was reading in some lecture notes, where the author says that you get the semigroup $(\mathbb{Z}_+, +)$ but he doesn't prove it; and I am very new to colimits :(

Comment: well, that's a very simple colimit actually; but before taking colimits — can you find $\pi_0\mathop{\mathcal I}(M_n(\mathbb C))$?

Comment: @GrigoryM I'm not sure... I need to know how many path components $\mathcal{I} (M_n(\mathbb{C}))$ has, and I am tempted to say it's $n$... but i can't see it rigorously because I am not sure how I can see the projections explicitly!

Comment: Can you find, say, $\pi_0 GL_n(\mathbb C)$?

Comment: @GrigoryM It's path-connected, so it's isomorphic to $ \mathbb{Z}$ , right?

Comment: Well, yes, it's path-connected, so $\pi_0$ is a 1-element set. Now you have to prove that all sets $\{A^2=A,\operatorname{rk}(A)=k\}\subset IM_n$ are path-connected, and basically you're done.

Comment: @GrigoryM  Alright, thanks... I'll try to prove it; one last thing if I may though...How come the colimit is $ \mathbb{Z}_+$?

Comment: Well, this is just colimit of sets of possible matrix ranks — i.e. of sets $\{0,...,n\}$ (wrt obvious inclusions) — and [such colimit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit#Examples) is just a union of all these sets